# delete method in mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I'm trying to create the CRUD operations in MongodB, but is unable to create the delete operations in this. the code below is for the animal shelter where I'm inserting the data first and then in the reading the data using the find keyword, I'm just confused about the delete operation, as i want to delete - say all the row. then how to use the

> **deletemany()**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

class AnimalShelter(object):

  """ CRUD operations for Animal collection in MongoDB """



  def __init__(self, username, password):

    # Initializing the MongoClient. This helps to 

    # access the MongoDB databases and collections. 

    if username and password:

      self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@localhost:27017' % (username, password))

    else:

      self.client = MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017')

    self.database = self.client['AAC']



# Complete this create method to implement the C in CRUD.

  def create(self, data):

    if data is not None:

      insert = self.database.animals.insert(data) # data should be dictionary 

      if insert!=0:

        return True

      else:

        return False      

    else:

      raise Exception("Nothing to save, because data parameter is empty")





  # Create method to implement the R in CRUD.

  def read(self,criteria=None):



    # criteria is not None then this find will return all rows which matches the criteria

    if criteria:

     # {'_id':False} just omits the unique ID of each row     

       

      data = self.database.animals.find(criteria,{"_id":False})

    else:

    #if there is no search criteria then all the rows will be return  

      data = self.database.animals.find( {} , {"_id":False})



    return data

   

  # The delete method in CRUD

(missing)
```

Comment: but how do i write in this @AyushGupta that is my question. I can too read the blogs  it's no brainer.

Comment: You managed to use `find` and `insert`, so what is the problem with `delete`? The syntax is the same.

Comment: # Create method to implement the R in CRUD.

def delete(self,criteria=None):
  #this will delete all the searches
  data = self.database.animals.deleteMany(criteria,{"_id":False})
  return data ........... does this work ? @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: No idea, I am not familiar with python. I assume `self.database.animals.deleteMany(criteria)` or `self.database.animals.deleteOne(criteria)` depending on your needs.

Comment: Check documentation for return document, it is like `{ "acknowledged" : true, "deletedCount" : 3 }` or `{ "acknowledged" : true, "insertedId" : ObjectId("56fc40f9d735c28df206d078") }` Perhaps `if insert!=0:` is not sufficient.